# Get date Minus 1 day but at exacty 4 AM

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013

I have the following sql server `WHERE` clause:

> WHERE (DateCreated >= CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 111) - 1)

This gets the date (where today is 2015-06-09) `2015-06-08`. I need to add a time to this as well like `2015-06-08 04:00:00` in 24H format. the time will always be the same bat every time the SQL command is executed, it should only be from yesterday at 4 AM to the current date and time.

how can this be achieved?

Comment: `DATEADD(HOUR, 4, DATECREATED)` ?

Comment: I would also recommend never using -1 or similar calculation with date / time fields. Using dateadd is a lot more clear about how much will actually be added / deducted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE DateCreated >= dateadd(d, datediff(d, 1, getdate()), '04:00')
```

Comment: Perfect Answer, Agree!

Comment: Awesome, never know `DATEDIFF` allowed you to use a starting date as an integer. *+1*

Comment: This works perfectly. thanks for the insight. I do not have a lot of experience with 'datediff' and I'm always keen on learning more. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for:

```
WHERE (DateCreated >= DATEADD(HOUR, 4, 
                        CONVERT(datetime, 
                            DATEADD(DAY, -1, CONVERT(date, GETDATE()) )
                               )
                              )
       )
```

Converting directly to `DATE` will take away the hassle of taking care of the hour part. After that, doing a `DATEADD` with `-1` will take you 1 day ago.

After this step, simply convert it back to datetime to create a timestamp part to your date, which is defaulted to `00:00:00.000`.

And in the end, simply add 4 hours to this start date, which will always give you 4:00 AM.